# Error when call method at third fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have sample program like at bellow that I have simplified. There is an error when I call a method in third fragment (`ListFragment`). Whereas there is alright when I call method in other fragment even though from third fragment.

When I change `ListFragment` to first or second fragment, then there is alright when I call a method inside `ListFragment`. And the substitutes fragment that I place in third fragment get error when I call a method on that.

I have no idea, where is my mistakes. Thank you very much for any answer.

Note: Error meaning that program close, and appear `"Unfortunately, program has stooped."`

Here's my program:

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import java.util.Locale;

import id.my.zain.tupperware.fragment.ItemFragment;
import id.my.zain.tupperware.fragment.ListFragment;
import id.my.zain.tupperware.fragment.UserFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private UserFragment userFragment;
    private ItemFragment itemFragment;
    private ListFragment listFragment;

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        userFragment = new UserFragment();
        itemFragment = new ItemFragment();
        listFragment = new ListFragment();

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = new Fragment();

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return fragment = userFragment;
                case 1:
                    return fragment = itemFragment;
                case 2:
                    return fragment = listFragment;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

UserFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import id.my.zain.tupperware.R;
import id.my.zain.tupperware.form.UserForm;

public class UserFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private UserForm form;
    private ItemFragment itemFragment;
    private ListFragment listFragment;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user, container, false);

        form = new UserForm(rootView);

        itemFragment = (ItemFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":1");
        listFragment = (ListFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":2");

        form.getUser_item().setOnClickListener(this);
        form.getUser_list().setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == form.getUser_item()) {
            itemFragment.user();
        }

        else if (v == form.getUser_list()) {
            listFragment.user();
        }
    }

    public void item() {
        int a = 1;
    }

    public void list() {
        int a = 1;
    }
}
```

ItemFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import id.my.zain.tupperware.R;
import id.my.zain.tupperware.form.ItemForm;

public class ItemFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ItemForm form;
    private UserFragment userFragment;
    private ListFragment listFragment;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, container, false);

        form = new ItemForm(rootView);

        userFragment = (UserFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":0");
        listFragment = (ListFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":2");

        form.getItem_user().setOnClickListener(this);
        form.getItem_list().setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == form.getItem_user()) {
            userFragment.item();
        }

        else if (v == form.getItem_list()) {
            listFragment.item();
        }
    }

    public void user() {
        int a = 1;
    }

    public void list() {
        int a = 1;
    }
}
```

ListFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import id.my.zain.tupperware.R;
import id.my.zain.tupperware.form.ListForm;

public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ListForm form;
    private UserFragment userFragment;
    private ItemFragment itemFragment;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

        form = new ListForm(rootView);

        userFragment = (UserFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":0");
        itemFragment = (ItemFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":1");

        form.getList_user().setOnClickListener(this);
        form.getList_item().setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == form.getList_user()) {
            userFragment.list();
        }

        else if (v == form.getList_item()) {
            itemFragment.list();
        }
    }

    public void user() {
        int a = 1;
    }

    public void item() {
        int a = 1;
    }
}
```

Error Logcat when I call method from UserActivity

```
11-11 13:21:09.273    2806-2806/id.my.zain.tupperware E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at id.my.zain.tupperware.fragment.UserFragment.onClick(UserFragment.java:42)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Error Logcat when I call method from ItemActivity

```
11-11 15:02:03.104    3291-3291/id.my.zain.tupperware E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at id.my.zain.tupperware.fragment.ItemFragment.onClick(ItemFragment.java:42)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post logcat please..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewPager` stores current,right and if any left fragments. When you are in `UserFragment` you only have `UserFragment` and `ItemFragment`. when you are in `ItemFragment` you have all your fragments. And when you are in `ListFragment` you only have `ListFragment` and `ItemFragment`.

You have a npe at `UserFragment`:

```
UserFragment.onClick(UserFragment.java:42)
```

This part of your code at `UserFragment`, causes your npe:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == form.getUser_item()) {
        itemFragment.user();
    }

    else if (v == form.getUser_list()) {
        listFragment.user();
       // debug here, you'll see that listFragment is null. thus listFragment.user() throws a npe.
    }
}
```

Because `listFragment` is null. It is a bad idea to handle click events of a fragment in another fragment. Try to put your click listeners in to the relevant fragments.

**EDIT:**
To solve your npe; consider my answer.
On `UserFragment`, you can have reference to `ItemFragment`.
On `ItemFragment`, you can have references to both `UserFragment` and `ListFragment`.
On `ListFragment`, you can have reference to `ItemFragment`.
Other references are going to make you get a npe.

But as I mentioned before, it is a bad desing to have direct references from fragments to fragments. See this document's [Communicating with the Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) part and implement something like that.

**EDIT 2:** For your implementation ViewPagers setOffscreenPageLimit method maybe a solution for you. Set it more than 2 and try again.

Comment: actually i send same value to third fragment and show it as listview.

Comment: in `ItemFragment`, i still have error call `ListFragment`. Or because `ViewPager` is define in `MainActivity` that automatically show `UserFragment`, so i can only call the left one (`ItemFragment`). And when i'm on `ItemFraagment`, the `ViewPager` isn't recalled.

Comment: try with ViewPagers setOffscreenPageLimit method. Set it to 2 maybe a soolution for you.

Comment: still not work. but thank you... you right about not communicate directly from fragment to fragment. i will try send to parent activity first

Comment: today i try again your solution, and its work. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad approach, you should not call other's fragment/activities methods from another activity or fragment, You can use Observer pattern to achieve this.

But Here is the updated code, it will work in your case.

p

```
ublic void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == form.getItem_user()) {
            if(usreFragment == null)
              {
               userFragment = new UserFragment();
             }
            userFragment.item();
        }

        else if (v == form.getItem_list()) {
             if(listFragment == null)
             {
                listFragment = new ListFragment();
             }            
             listFragment.item();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Store that data in public static variables, Or you can make another singleton class MyDataHolderClass, put data in it and then access saved data from other fragment where you want to use it.

Comment: public static isn't functioning well. and if use MyDataHolderClass, how to refrest `ListFragment` where i show `listview` data on that?

Comment: You should use observer pattern to achieve it. Check this link. http://www.vogella.com/articles/DesignPatternObserver/article.html