# Third Tab Receives Values Given to Second Tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-pageradapter

I have been stuck with this problem for a while now. I am making an app that has three almost identical fragments. I used [this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/) tutorial. I also tried passing data from MainActivity to all fragments (fragments being restaurantFragment, favouriteRestaurants, blockedRestaurants), and only ***the third one is problematic. Also when I change which data is sent to which tab - first and second tabs get the correct ones. The third tab is frequently not called at all, and if it is called it mostly gets the wrong data, unlike the other 2 tabs, and also no error is displayed when I select the third tab, and a lot of times when I try to evaluate number of tabs while debugging it often gets only 2 tabs***. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899947/error-when-call-method-at-third-fragment), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904265/ontabselected-selected-not-called), and a bunch of other solutions, but none of them worked for me.

**Sometimes if I select the third tab before the second it displays a correct list, but if I select the second one first it just copies it, instead of displaying correct values.**

MainActivity:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_one)));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_two)));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_three)));
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);

final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

PagerAdapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override    
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return MapsFragment.newInstance(restaurants);
        case 1:
            return RestaurantsFragment.newInstance(restaurants);
        case 2:
            return MyRestaurantsFragment.newInstance(restaurants);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Every Fragment looks identical, like this:

```
    public static MyRestaurantsFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Restaurant> restaurants) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("restaurants",restaurants);

    MyRestaurantsFragment fragment = new MyRestaurantsFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    restaurantList = (ArrayList<Restaurant>)getArguments().getSerializable("restaurants");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                     ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_restaurants, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.restaurants_list);
    adapter = new RestaurantsListAdapter(getActivity(), restaurantList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

content_main:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling `setUpWithViewPager(...)` ?

```
// Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

**Update**

To see titles, try to override `getPageTitle()` inside your `PagerAdapter`, like this:

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    if ( position == 0 ) {
        return "Title 1";
    } else if ( position == 1 ) {
        return "Title 2";
    } else {
        return "Title 3";
    }
}
```

Also, if you use `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager`, you can remove these parts of your code:

```
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_one)));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_two)));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_three)));
```

And

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

I'm supposing here that your layout is something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="top" />

 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**Update 2**

Try to change your `getItem` method in this way:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    if ( position == 0 ) {
        return MapsFragment.newInstance(restaurants);
    } else if ( position == 1 ) {
        return RestaurantsFragment.newInstance(restaurants);
    }

    return MyRestaurantsFragment.newInstance(restaurants);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Valentino. I tried this, but i still have the same error, and I also do not see tablayout names

Comment: I have added my layout as well. And even with the titles working the original problem is still present. The third tab is never displaying correct values. It copies the second tab.

Comment: Did you try to `return 3;` instead of `return mNumCounts;` inside `getCount()`?

Comment: Ok, the problem is your switch inside `getItem`

Comment: I've Updated the answer

Comment: Same problem again :( if I select the third fragment before the second it displays a correct list, but if I select the second one first it just copies it.

Comment: Try to change `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to `FragmentPagerAdapter`

Comment: Last thing is: why you have `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` inside `AppBarLayout`? Try to put them out of him

Comment: I did try that before but my app was not working properly. Fragments overlapped and were without any content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135847/discussion-between-valentino-s-and-kemo).

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the data to the adapter and call

```
 MyRestaurantsFragment tab3 = MyRestaurantsFragment.newInstance(restaurants);
```

instead of

```
MyRestaurantsFragment tab3 = new MyRestaurantsFragment();
```